# Removing Attributes with Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I'm able to ADD attributes with following Ansible code:  But cant figure out how to REMOVE attributes?
(I have tried adding "-" without quotes and with and a error is returned.

```
    - file:
        path: /tmp/null_p
        owner: foo
        group: bar
        mode: 0500
        attr: i
```

Above Adds immutable attribute to a file.

If i was doing this from command line, it would be

```
    chattr +i /tmp/null_p
```

to remove i would

```
    chattr -i /tmp?null_p
```

I would like to do this via attr instead of command in ansible.

I have referenced the ansible docs for this, but there are no examples for attributes http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/file_module.html

ansible version: 2.3.0.0
python version: 2.7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `attr` to a blank string or whatever the default is on your system.  For Ubuntu that is 'e'.

```
- file:
    path: /tmp/null_p
    owner: foo
    group: bar
    mode: 0500
    attr: e
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove the immutable attribute of a file in RHEL7/CENTOS using Ansible:

```
  - name: Remove immutable.
    become: yes
    file: 
      path: /etc/resolv.conf
      attributes: '-i'
```